# What is the equivalent "lifecycle_configuration=prevent_destroy" for aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to prevent a bucket's deletion in terraform. The bucket holds my terraform remote state files. Everywhere says to use `lifecycle_configuration=prevent_destroy`. The terraform docs say to use the new parameter `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`. I have that setup like so:

```
# Prevent deletion
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "tf_remote_state_s3_lifecycle_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.tf_remote_state.id
  rule {
    id     = "prevent_destroy"
    status = "Enabled"
  }
  
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
╷
│ Error: error creating S3 Lifecycle Configuration for bucket (XXXX): InvalidRequest: At least one action needs to be specified in a rule
│       status code: 400, request id: XXXX, host id: XXXX
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.tf_remote_state_s3_lifecycle_config,
│   on main.tf line 34, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "tf_remote_state_s3_lifecycle_config":
│   34: resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "tf_remote_state_s3_lifecycle_config" {
│ 
╵
```

What is the equivalent of `lifecycle_configuration=prevent_destroy` in `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing the `lifecycle` configuration of terraform and the `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` / `lifecycle_rule` which is an S3 feature controlling the lifycycle of objects in the bucket. The two have absolutely nothing to do with each other and for entirely unrelated things.

Solution: stick with / use `lifecycle { prevent_destroy = true }` on your `aws_s3_bucket`, do not use `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`.

https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration

Comment: You are right, I will accept this as the answer. Specifically, I confused the `lifecycle` parameter of terraform with the `lifecycle_rule` parameter of `aws_s3_bucket`. Tricky!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @luk2302 it is correct and yes @j7skov it is tricky as well.

At one side, it says deprecated and on the other hand it says to use "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration"